# How to force my EAR files to just be deployed on an specific server?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, deployment, weblogic, ear

I am developing an enterprise java application for a customer using J2EE technologies (JSF, EJB, Hibernate, etc). To avoid the customer to copy my .ear files and deploy them on another server (the AppServer is Weblogic), I am searching for a standard and secure method to bind my project output files into an specific physical server. This mean that I need my project output to be bound to a physical server at build time and the customer is just allowed to deploy then on an specific server.

Is there any standard method/library to do this or I should do it manually in my code using server identifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you will be able to 100% assure that a customer will be unable to copy, adapt and run your application to another server. First, an ear file is just a ZIP file, and classes inside are also easy to decompile and compile again, even if the EAR would be signed. So a lot of space to do some funny business :)

If you just wish to protect the customer from "accidentally" deploy your EAR on a second server, a first, easy and cheap step could be to link/insert the predicted host name (perhaps even the ip address) during the stage phase to a manifest or even java file (to make things more static). Then add an once initialized, later cached interceptor around all methods you would like to protect and check the local system (ie with InetAddress.getLocalHost()) against your preconfigured & linked host information. Still, very weak :/

Comment: The exact reason is that my developers sometimes update the customer version from the source they have on their laptop. I want to force them to just get the version from the build server and submit it to the customer. This makes me sure that I have the source code of every version in my source control.

Comment: You gave me a smile, because this is a problem unheard of ;-) If it's a maven project and the EAR is a module, why not add a unit test to the ear module that fails if the test is not running on the build server. You might even want to try to "override" the system property to skip tests in this particular modules pom, or code your own maven plugin to handle the whole story. Though honestly, I think we should try to change the mindset of developers and not the technology they use ;-)

Comment: You are right. Developer's mind should be changed. In addition, I need to make sure that the customer will not copy the project into a new server. BTW, the unit test is a good idea that I should work on it.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a MAVEN project you could add something to de settings.xml of the compilation server that allows things to run different on the configuration of the production system. Something like a different name for a datasource or something like that.